# Is there anything more I need to do aside from sign up to send materials to my great works?

Tags: simcity-2013

Once I've signed up to send materials to a great work site, (In this case plastic to a solar farm) do I need to do anything with my trade port specifically? Currently I have my plastic set to export from my trade port, and at one point my news flash said that materials being sent to the great work had stalled. Should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 4):

In order to send resources to a Great Work site, you need to **set that material to "Use Locally**" in your Trade Port/Depot in order for your trucks to send there. AFAIK, Export will NOT work.

[image: Use Locally]
[image: use Locally]

Comment: Import also works.  I've built a great work using only imported resources before, but its very expensive.